# automatic SE profile transfer for Autobiographer badge

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, stackexchange

I have noticed that when I sign up for most sites in the SE network, I automatically get the Autobiographer badge after a few minutes of interacting with the new SE site.   When I do, I look at my profile page and, indeed, my bio from Stackoverflow is populated there.

Ask Different appears not to do this.   Is there something I can do manually to associate my user with my SE profile bio — preferably something that does not involve a copy/paste of my bio?

Is there some bug in the Ask Different implementation that I am encountering, or was this a deliberate choice that was made when Ask Different was created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your highest rep profile is copied to any new sites you join at the time you create an account.

On the accounts tab on your profile, you can click

> Copy {site} Profile To Related Accounts

To copy a profile across the network.

Comment: Thank you, Jeff.  Worked great!